# How to optimize Multiple Retrofit Calls alongwith Tracking Progress and failures in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I have to make 50 REST calls using Retrofit in Android. I don't want to write `Call.enqueue` for each call, as It will increase length of code and not help me to track progress as well.

After Searching a lot, I found some people suggesting `Observable.zip` function of RxJava, which again is not suitable in my situation.

Kindly suggest an optimized way to make calls, as response of each call will be stored in SQlite Database.

Comment: "which again is not suitable in my situation." - what does it mean? What is your situation?

Comment: I have 50 calls for 50 Entities like   Entity1,Entity2....Entity50   ,, if I use `observable.zip` I have to club some entities like `Observable.zip(
        myApi.Entity1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), 
        myApi.Entity2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())) {
    a, b -> Pair(a, b)
}
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { Log.d(TAG, "$it")}`    for finding progress I have to boilerplate some code to formulate current progress and maintaining failed calls will also be clumpsy